# PHP array ouput shows only one element

Tags: php, arrays, video, youtube

I am working on a small PHP script that will take an array of youtube id's and generate an on the fly youtube embeded playlist.

The current PHP code I am using - only echos ONE video.

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/182oUgBfoLE?&rel=0&modestbranding=1&hd=1&autohide=1&playlist=
<?php
$videos = Array("PGNiXGX2nLU", "VUJOJ0d7e8c", "o0syTUu3_S0", "rXndd78C8-c" );
// Shuffle array
shuffle($videos);
// Loop array
foreach($videos as $video);
{
    // Echo array with commas between elements
    echo "$video ,";
}
?>
" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

My question is how can I get the all elements of the shuffled and looped array to be echoed ?

Comment: why are you passing array to url

Comment: I've edited your code so that it's more legible. Does it look like an accurate representation of the code you are actually using?

Comment: @VishnuBhadoriya he's not. The goal is to provide a playlist for the user

Comment: the question is now edited but he is passing array in url without use of implode

Comment: @VishnuBhadoriya Even before the edit, he was not passing an array to the URL. The code was difficult to read but not impossible; unless you are referring to an edit which did not make it into the revision history.

Comment: Your code looks ok to me but you should get rid of the semi-colon at the end of your `foreach($videos as $video);` <- here. Are you positive that YouTube supports the URL format your are trying to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My take

```
<?php

$videoIds = array("PGNiXGX2nLU", "VUJOJ0d7e8c", "o0syTUu3_S0", "rXndd78C8-c");
shuffle($videoIds);
$playlist = implode(',', $videoIds);

?>
<iframe width="560" height="315"
        src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/182oUgBfoLE?&rel=0&modestbranding=1&hd=1&autohide=1&playlist=<?= $playlist; ?>" 
        frameborder="0" allowfullscreen>
</iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this code -

```
<?php 
$videos = Array ( "PGNiXGX2nLU", "VUJOJ0d7e8c", "o0syTUu3_S0", "rXndd78C8-c" ); 
// Shuffle array 
shuffle($videos);
$playlist = implode(',', $videos);
?>

<iframe width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/182oUgBfoLE?&rel=0&modestbranding=1&hd=1&autohide=1&playlist=<?php echo $playlist;?>" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```